# Php web service to get data in json format

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, web-services

I have 2 database tables

1. `main_menu` which has 3 columns `id, item_name, img`
2. `sub_menu` which has columns `id, sub_item_name, item_name, add_price, img`

Now I am trying to get all sub menu under master menu when user clicks on master menu

eg.

```
select * from sub_menu where item_name="Cafe"
```

it should display all sub menu under `Cafe`.

And here is the web service I wrote to do that and get data in json format

```
    <?php
    $response = array();

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

   // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // check for post data
   if (isset($_GET["item_name"])) {


// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_menu WHERE item_name ='".$_GET["item_name"]."'");
echo $result;
if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $sub_menu = array();
        $sub_menu["id"] = $result["id"];
        $sub_menu["item_name"] = $result["item_name"];
        $sub_menu["sub_item_name"] = $result["sub_item_name"];
        $sub_menu["add_price"] = $result["add_price"];
        $sub_menu["img"] = $result["img"];
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["sub_menu"] = array();

        array_push($response["sub_menu"], $sub_menu);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No sub menu found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No menu found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
    } else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Now the problem is I am only getting first data only, it should display all data

Query is working fine in mysql, I checked that. The problem is somewhere in my php service.

Comment: Why do you expect to get all results if you only fetch one row? If you want to return all data, you need to call `mysql_fetch_array()` in a loop, and you need to make an array of all the results. Every PHP+MySQL tutorial shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `mysql_fetch_array()` in a loop, and add all the rows to an array. You can just copy the whole row of results in a single assignment, since you were using the same field names in your JSON as in the database.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $submenu = array();
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $submenu[] = $result;
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // user node
    $response["sub_menu"] = $all_results;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
```